# ASP.NET MVC 2: How do I make the Ajax.Form to fire the Client Side Validation with Data Annotation?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

Here is the code I have so far:

```
<% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>
<% using (Ajax.BeginForm("Address", "Accounts", FormMethod.Post, new AjaxOptions(){}, new { id="dialog-form"} )){ %>
     <div>
          <label for="address">Address Name:</label>
     </div>
     <div>
          <%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)%>
          <div>
               <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)%>
          </div>
     </div>
     <input type="submit" value="OK" />     
<% } %>
```

When I click submit, It does the validation on the server side, I kinda like it to validate on the Client instead of taking a trip to the server right away.

Answer (score 1):

did you include `~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js` and `~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcValidation.js` in your view.

Not all validation works client side, we'd need more detail to answer, what's are the attribute your using on your name property?

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the `Html.EnableClientValidation` method  as follows.

```
<% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>
<% using (Ajax.BeginForm("Address", ...) %>
```

Comment: I actually did call the
<% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>
on the master page.

Comment: It's not important. But are you sure it gets called before `BeginForm` method?